# Making the differentiation bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory

I read [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.10279), where the derivative operator is  made continuous by setting up a few assumptions. I thought, it would be enough to extend the sup-norm to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty,\infty} :=\|\cdot\|_\infty + \|\nabla_x \cdot\|_\infty$ to achieve that ([like here on SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364463/is-differentiation-as-a-map-discontinuous)). But the authors do additional things too.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact, convex set. We say the spatial derivative $\nabla_x\phi$ has a continuous extension to $\Omega$, if there exists $g\in C(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{k,d})$ such that $g|_{\Omega^\circ} = \nabla_x\phi$.

Let further

$$C^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^k) = \{\phi:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k | \phi \text{ continuously differentiable on } \Omega^\circ , \\ \nabla_x\phi \text{ has a continuous extension to }\Omega, \\||\phi||_{\infty,\infty} = \|\phi\|_\infty + \|\nabla_x\phi\|_\infty < \infty \}$$

It is said, that this makes $\nabla_x$ a continuous linear operator. Why is this continuous extension necessary?

Comment: Derivatives are defined on open sets, and $\Omega$ is compact.

Comment: I dont see how this matters here. But for the example in the linked thread, which was $C^1([0,1])$, this did not seem to matter.since the chosen norm guarantees a bounded gradient. If I extend the derivative to the boundary  or not, does not change the boundedness of $\nabla_x$, or does it?